# How to control the axis units in a map made with astropy and matplotlib?

Tags: astropy

When using astropy and matplotlib to create a map, the units in the right ascension axis are deg/min/sec, instead of h/m/s. I do not find an easy way in astropy to select the units h/m/s.

For example, if I try to reproduce the map of the Horsehead nebula as in the [documentation of astropy.wcs](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/wcs/index.html), I get a R.A. axis in deg/min/sec.

The code is simply:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename

filename = get_pkg_data_filename('tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits')
hdu = fits.open(filename)[0]
wcs = WCS(hdu.header)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111, projection=wcs)
plt.imshow(hdu.data, origin='lower', cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
plt.xlabel('RA')
plt.ylabel('Dec')
plt.show()
```

It is supposed to produce this:
correct units

[image: 1]

but I get that:

wrong units

[image: wrong units]

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ax = fig.gca()
ra = ax.coords[0]
ra.set_format_unit('hour')
```

e.g. as specified here: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/visualization/wcsaxes/controlling_axes.html

However, when I ran the same example, it defaulted to hours, so I'm not sure what configuration you have set that defaulted to degrees instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it does not fix the problem. The `set_format_unit('hour')` raises the error `TypeError: unit should be an astropy UnitBase subclass`. If I replace by `set_format_unit(unit.hour)`, there is no error message, but the unit in the map is not changed. 
Perhaps is it related to the fact that I am still using python 2.7 ?